# Replicate SQL Server 2012 publisher to 2008 subscriber?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2012

Microsoft isn't letting you own a Web Edition of SQL 2012 like they did with 2008. But 2012 Standard edition is way overkill for my needs.

Can I have a database server running 2012 Enterprise (or Standard) and use transactional replication to populate data on a 2008 Web Edition box? This would, of course, be 1-way replication only.

Thanks... trying to save a bunch of money on licensing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, replication is possible, as a subscriber only. See the `Replication` matrix in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Basically, SQL Server 2008 Web Edition supports as subscriber **only**:

1. Merge replication.
2. Transactional replication.
3. Snapshot replication.